# php SoapClient : param not showing up in request

Tags: php, .net, xml, web-services, soap

Why would my param p_oRSMasterFields not be present in the request? Is this request sent back from the soap server, could it be that the server rejects the data for that particular param and just blanks it out?

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);     

$client->UpdateCustMaster(array('p_iCompanyID' => 100, 
                               'p_lAccountNum' => 18087,   
                               'p_sSysUser' => 'WebTest',     
                               'p_oRSMasterFields' => 'THIS IS A TEST',
                               'p_lErrorCode' => 0
                                ));  

echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";  



REQUEST:

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.acme.com/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:UpdateCustMaster>
        <ns1:p_iCompanyID>100</ns1:p_iCompanyID>
        <ns1:p_lAccountNum>18087</ns1:p_lAccountNum>
        <ns1:p_sSysUser>WebTest</ns1:p_sSysUser>
        <ns1:p_oRSMasterFields/>
        <ns1:p_lErrorCode>0</ns1:p_lErrorCode>
    </ns1:UpdateCustMaster>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: What does the WSDL tell about that field?

Comment: <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:any namespace="http://www.acme.com/EnergyAPI/CustomerMaint/DSCustomerFields.xsd"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>

Not sure what that means exactly

Comment: If it's a sequence, it can't be a string I think. So the value get's dropped. You might want to use `'p_oRSMasterFields' => array('THIS IS A TEST'),` instead. But I'm not totally sure.

Comment: dosent matter what i put in there, still blank

Comment: harkre, thanks so much, you were correct, except in my case I had to do array('any'=>'THIS IS A TEST') for some god forsaken reason. guessing .net

Comment: yeah sure, `any` was so common I overlooked it, too. It belongs there, my fault, my suggestion was half done. Should I add it as an answer or do you want to answer your own?

Comment: sure add it as an answer. why is any so common, is it a .net webservice specific thing? i mean why would the rest of the params not need to be "any" and what the hell does any mean?

Comment: No such a common *word* that I overlooked it in your WSDL excerpt. So less programming language specific. I added an answer and also some explanation. WSDL works pretty well and easy with PHP SoapClient if you get used to it and gain more trust in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WSDL goes like that for that item:

```
<s:complexType>
  <s:sequence>
    <s:any namespace="acme.com/EnergyAPI/CustomerMaint/DSCustomerFields.xsd"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

So you need to give at least one `any` element in there:

```
$client->UpdateCustMaster(array('p_iCompanyID' => 100, 
                               'p_lAccountNum' => 18087,   
                               'p_sSysUser' => 'WebTest',     
                               'p_oRSMasterFields' => array('any' => 'THIS IS A TEST'),
                                                      ################################
                               'p_lErrorCode' => 0
                                ));
```

What happens behind the scene is that the PHP `SoapClient` class maps the information you pass in form of an array to the types specified in the WSDL. As your original one did not have any `any` elements/members, it was empty.